# find the location {x,y} of text in uilabel

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a string coming from server which I am displaying on UILabel multiligne. It is within that string, I am identifying some particular substring. I want to place a button on that substring(button will be a subview of UILabel). For this I require substring coordinates. I went through this but I am not able to understand it. Suppose my complete string is abc, 567-324-6554, New York. I want 567-324-6554 to be displayed on button for which I need its coordinates.
How can I use above link to find coordinates of substring?
Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

`UILabel` doesn't have any methods for doing this.  You can do it with [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITextView), because it implements the [`UITextInput` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput).  You will want to set the text view's `editable` property to `NO`.

Something like this untested code should work:

```
- (CGRect)rectInTextView:(UITextView *)textView stringRange:(CFRange)stringRange {
    UITextPosition *begin = [textView positionFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument offset:stringRange.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:begin offset:stringRange.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:begin toPosition:end];
    return [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
}
```

That should return a `CGRect` (in the text view's coordinate system) that covers the substring  specified by `stringRange`.  You can set the button's frame to this rectangle, if you make the button a subview of the text view.

If the substring spans multiple lines, the rectangle will only cover the first line.

Comment: i want find the x and y of this string"***" in the UITextView , can u help me thx bro

Comment: i try to do this  but its error                                 CGRect *varf= [self rectInTextView:select4 stringRange:@"***"];

Comment: You need to pass a `CFRange`, not an `NSString`, as the `stringRange` parameter.  Perhaps you will find `NSString`'s `rangeOfString:` method useful.

Comment: int beginIndex= [select4.text rangeOfString:@"***"].location;

Comment: CGRect varf= [self rectInTextView:select4 stringRange:beginindex];

Comment: I don't know what `beginindex` is, but it sounds like an `int`, not a `CFRange`.

Comment: As to “haw i call this function”, I don't know what function you mean.  If you mean `rangeOfString:`, you read the manual or look at one of the large number of sample code files that come up when you type `rangeOfString` into the search box at http://developer.apple.com.  Do your job!

Comment: int beginIndex= [Labelselect4 rangeOfString:@"***"].location;

Comment: If your text wraps, you may want to look at `selectionRectsForRange` instead, which returns an NSArray of rects.  Note though that it's only available on iOS 6.

Comment: can we do this for UILabel... because i have multiple lines of text for UILabel. I am displaying in UITableView. so the number Label is not formatting equal to the text label. PLease guide me