# How to find the position(x,y) of a letter in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a label with the text `@"Good,Morning"`

I want to find the position`(x,y) of letter ","(Comma)` in the label.

Can anyone tell & Suggest me that how to find this..

Comment: read @lemnar's answer in this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808974/uilabel-get-cgrect-for-substring-of-text

Comment: Have a look at the following links:
[First Link][1],
[Second Link][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191049/finding-location-of-specific-characters-in-uilabel-on-iphone
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654766/add-uigesturerecognizer-to-individual-letters-of-uilabel

Comment: This cannot be done with `UILabel` as per this Q&A: [find the location {x,y} of text in uilabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273889/find-the-location-x-y-of-text-in-uilabel). Read the answer to that question for a workaround

Comment: have you tried this?, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9274048/2629258

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
NSRange range = [@"Good,Morning" rangeOfString:@","];
NSString *prefix = [@"Good,Morning" substringToIndex:range.location];
CGSize size = [prefix sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(size.width, 0);
NSLog(@"p.x: %f",p.x);
NSLog(@"p.y: %f",p.y);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do you have an idea what to do if wants to find  second"o" in "Good, morning"?

Comment: 'sizeWithFont:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -sizeWithAttributes:

Comment: Does not work with multi-line label.