# Calculate where text starts on centre alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that I want to add a `UIView` exactly where the text starts.

The problem is that the text in the label is aligned to the centre so I don't know how to determinate where the actual text starts and where to position this `UIView`.

Any idea how can I calculate this thing?

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to calculate it? Why not use autolayout for that - center label to parent view, and set same with for your UIView. The label should have the exact size for your text.

Comment: @derdida The view is 1px width and 5px height, I want it to be exactly where the text starts. That's why I need to calculate it

Comment: and why not set to the left end of the textview? otherwise you could use "sizeToFit()" with your label, and get the size (label.frame.size.width)

Comment: @derdida That's a good, thanks!

Comment: it worked like this way?

Comment: @derdida Yep, SizeToFit()

Comment: Fine, nice to hear that! I will add that as answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use

```
yourLabel.sizeToFit()
```

to automatically resize your label for the space it needs. And then read out the frame of your label with:

```
yourLabel.frame.size (width or height)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIView` container which will wrap the `UILabel` and your new `UIView`. Then you can let the `UILabel` decides the width depending on its content and set it in the center of the container. Once you have this working you can just read the `UILabel` x to understand where it starts.

[image]

so the `UILabel` will have the constraints to `top`, `bottom`, the height you want and at center to horizontal whereas the little `UIView` to `top`, `bottom`, `height`, `width` and `leading` equal to `UILabel`

Comment: I don't really understand, can you please edit your answer with a quick example to help me understand better?

Comment: This is a description how solve that with autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

From :[How to find the position(x,y) of a letter in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650664/how-to-find-the-positionx-y-of-a-letter-in-uilabel)

```
NSRange range = [@"Good,Morning" rangeOfString:@","];
NSString *prefix = [@"Good,Morning" substringToIndex:range.location];
CGSize size = [prefix sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(size.width, 0);
NSLog(@"p.x: %f",p.x);
NSLog(@"p.y: %f",p.y);
```

you can modify it for your purpose

Answer (score 1):

you can get text size using "nsattributedstring"

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
label.text = "dshfk,j"
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

let string = label.attributedText
let width = string!.size().width
let height = string!.size().height

let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(width, height, width, height))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

then you can find rect using this ..

sample view

[image]